# Is it possible to handle a redirect after a page load with Apache?

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to handle a redirect with Apache(.htaccess) after a page load? If so, how (generalized solution)?

Is this the best way to do it?

I want to  perform a logout action (so the page must load first) and then perform a redirect to the login page, the thing is that I don't manage all the system after the login page, neither logout. So, is there a way to perform this or should I use a proxy or something?

Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology, I'm quite lost at this point.

Situation:
**I have this site with a login page, but then it goes to another port but the same site, I want to handle after the logout action a return to the login page that's why I'm looking to use apache because I don't have access to the files of that site(HTML, PHP, etc...).**

Any help is apppreciated.

Comment: Is there a posibility to execute a request through htacess then or even inject code through it?

Comment: You can not redirect from the server side, after the request is already finished. If you can not insert any additional client-side code by any other means, then I guess a proxy doing that somehow is the only real solution.